# get to file input in loginview from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, loginview, htmlcontrols

I'm trying to create a file upload, and am using the HTML control input (file) for this. Since this control is in a loginview, I can't  access it directly in code behind and have to use the  FindControl function like this:

```
this.LoginView1.FindControl("file_img_upload")
```

The problem is, I need to typecast the control to get access to the PostedFile attribute. Since Input is a HTML control, you can't seem to typecast it like, for example, a Button.

Is there a way to typecast this control or access it in any other way?

This is how the control is embedded in the loginview:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <p>U heeft geen toegang tot deze pagina als u niet ingelogd bent.</p>
  </AnonymousTemplate>
  <LoggedInTemplate>
    <div class="fifth">
       <input id="file_img_upload" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
       <asp:Button ID="btn_img_upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
                                    OnClick="btn_img_upload_Click"/>  
       <asp:Image ID="img_img_upload" runat="server" />
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_img_output" runat="server"  Text="Label"></asp:Label> 
    </div>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use the FileUpload web control, since it's one of its properties you're trying to access?

Comment: It's indeed much easier to use the control! (I'm really new to ASP and didn't know there was one) I'm now using it and it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use the ASP FileUploadControl, which is accessable from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You will find as a `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile` control if you add the runat="server" attribute.

```
<input id="file_img_upload" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" />
```